# Presto's support for approx_distinct

Tags: presto, approximate, hyperloglog

I am evaluating distributed query engines for analytical queries (both interactive as well as batch) on large scale data (~100GB). One of the requirements is low latency (<= 1s) for count-distinct queries, where approximate results (with up to 5% error) are acceptable.

Presto seems to support this with its approx_distinct(). As far as my understanding goes, it uses HyperLogLog for that. However, unless the data is persisted in rolled-up form, along with the HyperLogLog values, it would have to be computed on the fly. I do not think my queries would finish within a second for large datasets.

Does it support rollup with HyperLogLog computation at ingestion time (similar to Druid)? Given that unlike Druid, Presto queries the data from external stores (Hive/Cassandra/RDBMS etc.), I am not sure that ingestion time rollups are supported, unless Presto's native store supports them. Can someone please confirm?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't such a thing as "Presto's native store". Presto is query execution engine with connector architecture allowing plugging in multiple storage layers.

If you want an approximate count-distinct for a whole data set, you can compute table stats (When using Presto with Hive, this currently needs to be done in Hive).

If you want an approximate count-distinct for a dynamic selection of data, you still need to read the data. Then you won't get to second latency with such big data set. However, you can combine `approx_distinct` (or use plain `count(distinct ..)`) with [`TABLESAMPLE`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#tablesample) to limit the size of data read.

Comment: Thanks @piotr-findeisen. The queries will be approximate count-distinct queries on a subset of dimensions, with filters on one or more of the dimensions. Regarding Presto's native store, I was referring to the passing mention in [this link](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=6684678). Was wondering if it has been productionized by now. Thanks for the pointer to TABLESAMPLE. Will explore it.

Comment: Perhaps this is about Raptor (connector and data storage in one), but I won't be elaborate on that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [Verdict](http://verdictdb.org/), which can significantly reduce query processing cost by applying statistics and approximate query processing, yielding 99.9% accuracy. It runs on all SQL-based engines including Apache Hive, Apache Impala, Apache Spark, Amazon Redshift, etc..

You can download source code from [here](http://verdictdb.org/download/). After downloading and some simple setup, you can issue query as you normally do and get results in a much shorter time.